# Help parsing a sentence with two を

Tags: particles, particle-を, relative-clauses, subjects, object

Context: in the [Dead Tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_Tube) manga, a villain is talking about how she turned people into zombies by giving them a hallucinogenic drug and explains that they are "contagious".

> その薬の濃度**を**メチャクチャ濃くしたヤツ**を**ゾンビ達の歯や爪に　たっぷりつけておいたの！　要するに…　今後はゾンビに襲われた者はゾンビに感染する！

Could you help me parse the first sentence? I understand that the first part (その薬の濃度をメチャクチャ濃くしたヤツ) is a relative clause meaning "Those (zombies) in which the drug is extremely concentrated". What confuses me is that second を. What is the verb for this object? It has to be つけた, right? But it doesn't make much sense. Also, if ヤツ refers to zombies, why is there another reference to them (ゾンビ達) after the second を？

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/Gu9tXIG.jpg) you can see the original page. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Isn't this ヤツ referring to the "stuff" which contains the highly concentrated drug? She applies this to the teeth and blood of the zombies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「その薬{くすり}の濃度{のうど}をメチャクチャ濃{こ}くしたヤツ**を**ゾンビ達{たち}の歯{は}や爪{つめ}**に**たっぷりつけておいたの！」

The origin of your confusion is both grammar and vocabulary.

This sentence says:

> "I applied a ton of その薬の濃度をメチャクチャ濃くしたヤツ to the ゾンビ達の歯や爪."

As stated by @user3856370 in the comment, the 「ヤツ」 refers to the highly concentrated ***version*** of this drug.  It does not refer to the zombies at all.

その薬の濃度をメチャクチャ濃くした modifies ヤツ.  Therefore, two を's are needed. In a word, 「ヤツ」 is the object of this sentence, so it takes the second を.  (The first を is used in the relative clause.)

The verb is 「つけておいた（の）」 ("applied").

The unmentioned subject of the sentence is the speaker (as usual).  So, we have:

> 「（私は） object を location に verb.」

In other words, this is a very normal sentence as far as grammar.